# Reputation Loss

Tags: support

could a moderator please tell my why I lost all of my reputation on Serverfault?

If this info is required, I believe I lost it last night at around 9 PM EST.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You picked up a -100 from spam/offensive flags - you can see this in your reputation history by going to https://serverfault.com/reputation

I don't agree with those flags, it's a bad answer and has gotten proper down votes, but I don't think it was serious enough to deserve that smack down and I have cleared the flags. This is the answer in question: https://serverfault.com/questions/113332/error-installing-sql-server-2005-express-on-amd-turion/309582#309582

Comment: Doesn't deserve the spam flag, but still a bad answer...+1 to Zypher. -1 to Richard's "answer"

Comment: I apologize for that answer. Thank you for informing  me of why it happened. It wont happen again.

Comment: Not spam but definitely offensive. Nevertheless, it deserved downvotes and deletion, not -100 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a temporary ban - did you do something which could be construed as obnoxious?

https://serverfault.com/users/93722/richardp?tab=reputation shows your reputation history - looks like it's still there but overridden at the moment.